# Chevalley-Solomon formula and Weyl character formula

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, reductive-groups, coxeter-groups, weyl-group

Let $\Phi\subset V$ be a root system of rank $r$ with Weyl group $W$, a choice of positive roots $\Phi_+$ and exponents $d_1, \ldots, d_r$ (i.e. the invariant algebra $(\operatorname{Sym}^\bullet V)^W$ is polynomial in generators of degree $d_1+1, \ldots, d_r+1$). Then the Chevalley-Solomon formula says that
$$\sum_{w\in W} q^{\ell(w)}=\prod_{\alpha\in \Phi_+} \frac{(1-q^{\operatorname{ht}(\alpha)+1})}{(1-q^{\operatorname{ht}(\alpha)})}=\prod_{i=1}^r (1+q+\cdots + q^{d_i}).$$
This is extremely reminiscent of the Weyl character formulas, but I can't quite see how to relate the two. Is it possible to prove the Chevalley-Solomon formula from the Weyl character formula or a variant of it, or is there any representation-theoretic interpretation of the Chevalley-Solomon formula that would explain why it takes a form so similar to Weyl's character formula?

Comment: Sorry, I meant: is it not just the $q$-Weyl dimension formula for $V_{\rho}$ where $\rho = \omega_1 + \cdots + \omega_n = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\alpha \in \Delta_+} \alpha$ is the Weyl vector?

Comment: What is the $q$-Weyl dimension formula?

Comment: I mean the standard $q$-analog of the Weyl dimensional formula. See for example Lemma 2.5 of Stembridge's "On Minuscule Representations, Plane Partitions And Involutions In Complex Lie Groups" (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-94-07320-1, available on his webpage https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~jrs/papers.html).

Comment: @SamHopkins I don't see how this gives the Chevalley-Solomon formula. How do you go from the $q$-dimension of $V_\rho$ to $\sum_w q^{\ell(w)}$?

Comment: Yes, it does not quite match. My thought was that because $\rho$ is the first example of a strictly dominant (integral) weight, it will have all weight spaces $w\rho$ for $w\in W$ distinct. But I guess its dimension will be larger than $\#W$. So maybe what you need is Lusztig's $q$-analog of weight multiplicity instead...